# How do search engines do exact phrase matches on millions (or billions of documents)?

Tags: web, full-text-search

It would seem to be impossible to do an exact phrase match on billions of documents, how do search engines do it?

My only guess is that they do not actually do a real exact phrase match. They have a word index that returns every document that contains a particular word and then they cherry pick words out of the "exact phrase" and intersect the word lists. For example, when I search for "cut down tree" on Google one page I get is [How to Cut Down a Tree](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Cut-Down-a-Tree-And-Make-Firewood/) on Instructables, but nowhere on this page is there the exact phrase "cut down tree". The closest thing is "Cut Down a Tree" which is a different phrase. So, apparently Google is not really doing an exact phrase match, just a pseudo-match.

So, is doing a real exact match impossible with a large corpus?

Comment: Google used to do exact phrase matching *exactly*, sans casing and some non-letter characters, until maybe a few years ago or less (and it used to be a better search engine ~2010 and before, for me, anyway). I noticed because I've used that feature heavily for many years. They're not using the same methods they used to. They dropped exact phrase matching, and now do approximations: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-apply-close-variant-keyword-matching-exact-phrase-keywords/114067/

Comment: So, anyway, I don't know how they *used* to do it, but it wasn't impossible. I could envision some ways, maybe, though, but I don't have a lot of experience with that sort of thing; so, I'm not making all this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know much about a large corpus like Google , but I have my own experiences with Apache Solr . To do an exact search in Solr , you have to pass your phrase in quotes , like "Google search mystery" . However, such kind of query only limits you to only the exact matches, but not the other documents which may contain either words like Google search, search mystery, Google mystery or more such real world combination. So here comes in boost related queries that you give relative boost values to keywords so that exact word comes at the top, but also the subsequent matches also come up . My Solr based application has  an index of about 1,00,000 documents and it worked fine. Also my application had a specific use-case for exact  content based search , which works well at a small level. Now , in a Google query scenario , i don't think their search model will sort down things on exact matches only and it probably makes sense . Because when you search for "cut down tree" may be there are results that contain that exact phrase  ,but that website may not be deemed as relevant to the user , as Google considers a lot of factors , like page visits, back links to the page ,popular content that is widely searched on a regular basis . So exact match is not only a parameter that a search engine like google will keep in mind while scooping out the best from millions of documents .

Answer (score 0):

To come to your example "a" in "cut down a tree" is probably a stopword and excluded from indexing and querying.

So how do search engines work? They maintain an inverted index, that is an index of words and which document they occur in. In addition they keep a term position, that is, where the words occur in the document. That way they can gather a list of documents that match the query but also perform operations such as phrase and proximity matching.

For example we may have the terms

```
Term    Doc    Pos
cut     1      7
        5      27
down    1      8
        5      7
tree    1      9
        5      98
```

we can see that Doc 1 and Doc 5 match but only Doc 1 matches the phrase (excluding stopwords).

Comment: You are basically repeating what I already said in my question.

Comment: No I'm explaining how you do phrase matching (using term positions) on a large body of documents and why "a" may not be taken into account for the purposes of querying/indexing.